# Select Timeout error in Ubuntu14.04 with camera Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I am trying to use a webcam for my project. I use Opencv2.4.11 and the Logicool webcam C270.
I wrote a very simple code shown on below.

```cpp
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat frame;
  VideoCapture capture(0); // open the default camera
  if (!capture.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

  namedWindow("CVtest",1);

  while (true) {
    capture >> frame;
    imshow("CVtest", frame);
    waitKey(20);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but this code is not work for me. I get this error messages.

```
jiehunt@ubuntu:~/work/test$ ./test.out 
init done 
opengl support available 
select timeout
select timeout
```

I found this page [Select Timeout error in Ubuntu - Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715209/select-timeout-error-in-ubuntu-opencv?lq=1) , and I followed the step

```sh
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=6000 quirks=0x80
```

It doesn't work for me.
When I turned on the trace of uvcvideo, I got this error message.

```sh
[13087.385542] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
[13087.385545] uvcvideo: Frame complete (EOF found).
```

And now, I don't know what I should do.

My camera formats are shown bellow.

```sh
jiehunt@ubuntu:~/work/test$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
  Index       : 0
  Type        : Video Capture
  Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
  Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

  Index       : 1
  Type        : Video Capture
  Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
  Name        : MJPEG
```