# 'select timeout' error while running python opencv script

Tags: python, opencv, linux-kernel, webcam, uvc

I'm trying to capture video/image feed from a USB 3.0 webcam. When ever I try to run this code,the code runs and captures feed. But, after a while I get 'select timeout'.
The error is not grabbed by exception.
Can someone help me with this issue?

```sh
select timeout

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total() == 0 || data != __null) in Mat, file /home/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 500
```

```
try:

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret != True:
            break
        if stat == None:
            stat = ret
            print('[INFO] ---- Reading video feed')
            continue
        frame = cv2.resize(frame , (int(320/2),int(240/2)))
        video.write(frame)
        if stat1 == None:
            stat1 = ret
            print('[INFO] ---- Video recording on process')
            continue
        c+=1
        print(c)
        key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
        if key == 27:
            break
        elif c == 1200:
            break
except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        sys.exit()
```

I have also tried editing the 'uvcvideo' driver parameters

```sh
$ modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=6000
```

And also,
Enabled module traces,

```sh
$ sudo echo 0xffff > /sys/module/uvcvideo/parameters/trace
```

Observed these errors on 'dmesg' [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PglV2.jpg)

Link which I followed:
[Select Timeout error in Ubuntu - Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715209/select-timeout-error-in-ubuntu-opencv)